# Phase response of $H(f)=e^{-j2{\pi}ft_0}$

Tags: fourier-transform, phase, frequency-response, magnitude

Given is the impulse response: $$h(t)=\delta(t-t_0)$$.

I calculated $$H(f)=e^{-j2 \pi ft_0}=|H(f)|\cdot e^{j\varphi(f)}$$.

Now, the magnitude response of $H(f)$ is:

$$\begin{align}
|H(f)| &=\sqrt{\Re\{H(f)\}^2+\Im\{H(f)\}^2} \\ 
 &= \sqrt{\cos^2(2{\pi}ft_0)+\sin^2(2{\pi}ft_0)} \\
 &= 1 \\
\end{align}$$.

Using: $$e^{-j \theta}=\cos(\theta)- j \cdot \sin(\theta)$$ and $$\cos^2(\theta)+\sin^2(\theta) = 1$$.

But now I wonder about the solution of the phase response. I know that the solution is:

$$\varphi(f)=-2 \pi f t_0$$.

I would be thankful if someone could show me how the phase response was calculated, since following

$$\varphi(f) = \arctan \left(\frac{\Im\{H(f)\}}{\Re\{H(f)\}} \right) = \arctan \left(\frac{-\sin(2 \pi f t_0)}{\cos(2 \pi f t_0)} \right)$$

I instead obtain $$\varphi(f)=-\arctan\big(\tan(2{\pi}ft_0)\big)$$ which differs from the given sample solution.

Comment: try plotting both in matlab and see if there is a difference

Comment: $$\varphi(f) = \arctan \left(\frac{\Im\{H(f)\}}{\Re\{H(f)\}} \right)$$ is not always correct.  it is correct when $\Re\{H(f)\}>0$ but is off by an amount of $\pm \pi$ when $\Re\{H(f)\}<0$.  you need to check out the [complex argument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_(complex_analysis)),

Answer (score 4):

Wouldn't it be much easier to just compare the left-hand side and the right-hand side of

$$e^{-j2\pi ft_0}=|H(f)|e^{j\phi(f)}\tag{1}$$

to see that $|H(f)|=1$ and $\phi(f)=-2\pi ft_0$?

Comment: Plants face in hand - sometimes a little bit of insight beats a lot of mathematics :)

Answer (score 0):

$\varphi(f)=-\arctan(\tan(2{\pi}ft_0)) = -2{\pi}ft_0$

Which is the solution

Comment: it is the solution as long as $$ \big|2 \pi f t_0 \big| < \frac{\pi}{2} $$

Comment: i might suggest that both Zelda and Eddy review the notion of ***phase wrapping*** and unwrapping phase, which is also the difference between the Principal Value of $\operatorname{Arg}(\cdot)$ and the unwrapped $\arg(\cdot)$.  that might solve the problem.

Comment: @robert - his solution is in his question:

"I know that the solution is:

φ(f)=−2πft0".

Unwrapping is not required?

Comment: yeah, but the question he asks is essentially *"How does...*

$$\begin{align}
\varphi(f) &= \arctan \big(-\tan(2 \pi f t_0) \big) \\
&= -2 \pi f t_0 \\
\end{align} $$ "?

and the answer will be about both what the complex $\arg\{ \cdot \}$ is and what phase wrapping and unwrapping are.

Comment: @Robert ah I see, I have not seen this question formatted this way (with real frequency), usually this would be set in H(e^jw) form - in which case that explanation would be extraneous to the solution. I would like to just ask your opinion additionally, do you agree with the question terminology as originally set? It says H(f) and not H(e^jw) or H(e^jf....), is this interchangable in this way?

Comment: As the question stands (after I edited it), I agree with the terminology of the question.  It's a question in the "analog" (or more precisely, the "continuous-time") domain.  So I don't think that "$H(e^{j \omega})$" is appropriate.  I think that either "$H(j\Omega)$" (if you need to do things Laplacian $H(s)$)  or "$H(f)$" (if you want to do things Fourierian) are the appropriate terminology.